# How to center the title in the header with css flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a simple header with css flexbox. The header has two elements, a link on the left with an arrow and a title which has to be in the center of the `header`.

Here a codepen demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzmZxg

This is the css

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.header__link {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  align-self: center;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.header__title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

As you can see in the demo, the title is in the center of his own block and not all the `header` element.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve it with the same html and using css flexbox?

If you edit the codepen i can accept the answer.

Comment: Centered vertically or horizontally? Or both?

Comment: text has to be centered horizontally in the header

Comment: Flex-box won't work for you then. You'll have to absolute position your link element within the header, then just text-align: center

Comment: One pseudo element and `flex-grow: 1`, and you're done. Flexbox can do this. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLRxWo

Comment: @Michael_B correct